# Not able to create a directory in hadoop file system

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-manager

Getting this problem while creating a directory in hadoop file system
    mkdir: Permission denied: user=ubuntu, access=WRITE, inode="/user/ubuntu":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x

Comment: You should create the directory as `hduser` not as `ubuntu` user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved in two ways :-

1) Run the command using hdfs user

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/ubuntu/
```

2) Change the ownership of the folders using the hdfs user so that you may not face problems while creating directories inside it or using it.

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -chowm ubuntu:ubuntu /user/ubuntu/
```

Now user ubuntu will take the ownership of the ubuntu directory in Hadoop file system.

Comment: you may use hadoop fs -mkdir "name of the folder"  
for eg:

hadoop fs -mkdir /user/training/folder

Answer (score 1):

You should create this as hduser and not ubuntu user. This should work:

**sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdr $dir**